# Laravel 5.3 not installed

Tags: php, laravel, installation, laravel-5.3

I am feeling difficulties in  installing `laravel5.3` framework, problem is that when i install latest version by composer with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`  it automatically install `laravel 5.2` instead of `laravel 5.3

when i changes `laravel 5.2` to `laravel 5.3` in `composer.json` file and run `composer update` it gives error like this.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.3.9 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.8 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.7 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.6 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.5 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.4 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.3 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.28 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.27 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.26 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.25 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.24 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.23 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.22 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.21 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.20 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.2 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.19 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.18 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.17 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.16 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.15 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.14 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.13 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.12 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.11 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.10 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.1 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.0 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.6.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.0, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.20, v5.3.21, v5.3.22, v5.3.23, v5.3.24, v5.3.25, v5.3.26, v5.3.27, v5.3.28, v5.3.3, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9].
```

But i have new install xampp which shows my `PHP version` is  `7.0.13`(checked by this echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();)
What's happening ? why i could not install Laravel 5.3?

Comment: check laravel version first as  `php artisan --version`

Comment: and try to run composer install instead of composer update

Comment: are you on ubuntu?

Comment: composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.3.0 projectName --prefer-dist

Comment: I am on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's better to install a fresh Laravel 5.3 instead upgrade it. It's more work but avoid many issues.

Before run `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`, compare your system configuration with [laravel 5.3 require configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3#installation)

**UPDATE**
You can try `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel=5.3.* blog` for specific laravel version and then run `composer update`.

Comment: i tried that also but this automatically install Laravel5.2 not Laravel5.3

Comment: Your php version?

Comment: @RanjeetKarki See my *UPDATE* and let me know the result

Comment: gives error 

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.3.* in a version inst
  allable using your PHP version 5.6.3.


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]

Comment: It means that your PHP version is `5.6.3` not `7.0.13`. For confirmation you can run command `php -v`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should update your php version (use 7.0) because laravel 5.3 is usually work with php7.0 ,
then after you should change your laravel version in composer.json from 5.2 to 5.3 and then run composer update !!!!!!
Everything will be fine.

Comment: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
The above command solved my issue.